# SQL query to transform combination of values into a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a table like this:

```
user_id, gender, sent
1        M       100
1        F       120
2        M       20
2        F       30
```

I want a table like this from the above:

```
user_id, male_sent, female_sent, total_sent 
1        100        120          220 
2        20         30           50
```

I lack the (Postgres) SQL foo to figure this one out.

Comment: Hi, I am using PSQL, I tagged it with psql.

Comment: Have you had a look at the tag description of `psql`? You are probably talking talking about PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oops, you are right. psql != postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
select user_id,
  sum(case when gender = 'M' then sent else 0 end) male_sent,
  sum(case when gender = 'F' then sent else 0 end) female_sent,
  sum(sent) total_sent
from yourtable
group by user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1dc6/3)

Answer (score 2):

What database are you using?

If you are using SQL Server, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT user_id,sum(case when gender = 'M' then sent else 0 end) as male_sent,
sum(case when gender = 'F' then sent else 0 end) as female_sent,
sum(sent) as total_sent
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY user_id
```